# "Screws vs. Nails: When Do You Use One or the Other"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

> Screws vs. Nails: When Do You Use One or the Other?

This is a real heading from lifehacker.com.

It is confusing to me that the first part uses the plural number while the second one uses the singular. Is it grammatical at all? And maybe it would be better to change it to

> Screws vs. Nails: When to use which ones?

Comment: Where is singular plural?

Comment: "Screws vs. Nails" uses plural form. "When Do You Use One or the Other" uses the singular form. Isn't?

Comment: 'One' refers to 'one type of fixing' rather than 'one screw'.

Comment: @KateBunting Now it makes more sense :-)

Comment: @KateBunting Do you consider my own version as wrong?

Comment: @jsv your version is grammatical, but much more awkward. The original version is perfectly fine, no need to look for any changes.

Comment: No, it's a possible version. I was explaining why they had used the singular.

Comment: The second blockquote suggestion would run better as "Screws vs. nails: which to use?"